# Creating SQL Server 2012 Database Projects using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a SQL Server 2012 Database Project using Visual Studio 2010.

Can you do this with VS 2010 Professional (after downloading SSDT) or do I have to upgrade to Premium

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure is there something like SQL Server 2012 Database Project for VS yet. However You could try this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027